# big query geospatial data type conversion

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, geospatial

[image]

I have a column named geospacial_valid. Above is one row data example. The string mixed with string and number. How do I convert to a polygon type(shown below) in big query.

I have not seen this datatype before.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the string value instead of an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the data in your column `GeoSPatialValid` is in hex or bytes. You can convert bytes or hex to GEOGRAPHY data type by using [ST_GEOGFROM()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_geogfrom). Using the converted value from `ST_GEOGFROM()` you can convert it to GeoJson using [ST_ASGEOJSON()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_asgeojson).

As an example I used this valid geodata in bytes:
[image]

Using this query I convert it to `GEOGRAPHY` and GeoJSON:

```
SELECT ST_GEOGFROM(GeoValid) as geo,
       ST_ASGEOJSON(ST_GEOGFROM(GeoValid)) as geojson 
FROM `dataset.test_table`
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your string appears (I'm not sure) to be HEX-encoded EWKB string.

If this is the case, it might not work, as BigQuery only supports WKB but not EWKB (EWKB adds SRID specification and potentially M/Z dimensions).

You can try `ST_GeogFrom(geo)`, or `ST_GeogFromWkb(From_Hex(geo))` but I think these would fail due to SRID / EWKB issue above.

I would try to convert to plain GeoJson or WKT text in the source system this came from, most systems support `ST_AsGeoJson` function or similar, and then convert GeoJson to Geography in BigQuery using `ST_GeogFromGeoJson`.